# Binary variable to multiple records of same key based on characters in another field in R

Tags: r, binary, records, indicator

I have a table of doctor visits wherein there are sometimes multiple records for the same encounter key (`Enc_Key`) if there are multiple diagnoses, such as:

```
Enc_Key | Patient_Key |   Enc_Date   | Diag
  123         789         20160512      asthma
  123         789         20160512      fever
  123         789         20160515      coughing
  546         013         20160226      flu      
  564         444         20160707      laceration
  789         226         20160707      asthma
  789         226         20160707      fever
```

I am trying to create an indicator variable `Diag_Ind` based on the value of the character variable `Diag`, but I need to apply it for the entire encounter. In other words, if I get a value of "asthma" for `Diag` for a record, then I want to apply a "1" for the `Diag_Ind` to every record that has the same `Enc_Key`, such as below:

```
Enc_Key | Patient_Key |   Enc_Date   | Diag            | Diag_Ind
  123         789         20160512      asthma             1
  123         789         20160512      fever              1
  123         789         20160515      coughing           1
  546         013         20160226      flu                0     
  564         444         20160707      laceration         0
  789         226         20160707      asthma attack      1
  789         226         20160707      fever              1
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to apply this binary indicator to multiple records. I have been using a line of code that resembles this:

```
tbl$Diag_Ind <- ifelse(grepl('asthma',tolower(tbl$Diag)),1,0)
```

but this would only assign a value of "1" to the single record with that **Diag** value, such as this:

```
Enc_Key | Patient_Key |   Enc_Date   | Diag            | Diag_Ind
  123         789         20160512      asthma             1
  123         789         20160512      fever              0
  123         789         20160515      coughing           0
  546         013         20160226      flu                0     
  564         444         20160707      laceration         0
  789         226         20160707      asthma attack      1
  789         226         20160707      fever              0
```

I'm unsure of how to apply it to the rest of the records with the same `Enc_Key` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use base R `ave` to check if any value in every group of `Enc_Key` has `asthma` in it

```
df$Diag_Ind<- ave(df$Diag, df$Enc_Key,FUN=function(x) as.integer(any(grep("asthma", x))))

df
#  Enc_Key Patient_Key Enc_Date       Diag Diag_Ind
#1     123         789 20160512     asthma        1
#2     123         789 20160512      fever        1
#3     123         789 20160515   coughing        1
#4     546          13 20160226        flu        0
#5     564         444 20160707 laceration        0
#6     789         226 20160707     asthma        1
#7     789         226 20160707      fever        1
```

---

Similar solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(Enc_Key) %>%
 mutate(Diag_Ind = as.numeric(any(grep("asthma", Diag))))

#   Enc_Key Patient_Key Enc_Date    Diag    Diag_Ind
#    (int)       (int)    (int)     (fctr)    (dbl)
#1     123         789 20160512     asthma        1
#2     123         789 20160512      fever        1
#3     123         789 20160515   coughing        1
#4     546          13 20160226        flu        0
#5     564         444 20160707 laceration        0
#6     789         226 20160707     asthma        1
#7     789         226 20160707      fever        1
```